# Cannot mount windows 10 shares using open-vmware-tools, vmworkstation12, and Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: mount, vmware

**Update:**
I think this might be resolved by installing open-vmware-tools v10, but I can't find the package for Ubuntu 14.04.
VMWare has some packages [here](http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/repos/index.html),  but they don't include 14.04, and I can't find the package in any of the normal Ubuntu repositories.  Does anyone know

---

were I can find the version 10 open-vmware-tools package for Ubuntu 14.04?

I have followed the instructions for setting up the shares in vmworkstation as shown in the screenshot at the bottom and I can confirm that they are available by running.

```
$ vmware-hgfsclient
portable
old_windows_7
```

I have also create a mount point /mnt/hgfs as seen here:

```
$ ls -l /mnt
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 17 23:12 hgfs
```

however when I try to mount any of the shares I get the following error.

```
$ sudo vmware-hgfsmounter .host:/portable /mnt/hgfs
Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Here is the screenshot of the vmware share settings.

[image: vmware share settings]